# i cant find a way to fix this unity3d action map script error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: actions maps]

[image: script]

I got this error and I can't find a way to fix it
here is the error:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private Playerinput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    void Awake() 
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OnEnable() 
    {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable() 
    {
        onFoot.Disable();
    }
}
```

> 'PlayerInput' does not contain a definition for 'OnFoot' and no accessible extension method 'OnFoot' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerInput' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]

Answer (score 1):

General note: Unity `InputSystem` package already brings its own type called `UnityEngine.InputSystem.PlayerInput`.

=> Are you sure, you are referencing the correct type?

---

If I

- replicate your settings in a new project
- make sure the `Generate c# class` is enabled

  [image]
- make sure to hit `Save Asset`

  [image]
- make sure the correct `PlayerInput` type is referenced

then I can access

```
var playerInput = new PlayerInput();
var onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work :/, thx anyways tho.